# Xlswriter: Removing frozen pane border lines

Tags: xlsxwriter

I am using `worksheet.freeze_panes` to create a frozen pane. It works fine, except that it draws the pane borders across my spreadsheet. Is there any way to remove these lines? I tried formatting the individual cells, removing their borders, but to no avail.

Comment: Are you sure it is possible to do that in Excel?

Comment: In that case it can't be done in XlsxWriter. `;-)`